# FullCalendar C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

Eu gostaria de abrir um modal quando clicasse em um dia no calendário.

script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,listWeek'
            },
            views: {
                listWeek: { buttonText: 'Compromissos' }
            },
            defaultView: 'month',
            defaultDate:  '@(ViewBag.HoraHoje)',
            navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable: false,
            eventLimit: false, // allow "more" link when too many event
            selectable: true,
            dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view, resourceObj) {
                $('#id01').dialog();
}
        });

    });
</script>
```

html:

```
    <body>
<div id="calendar"></div> 
<div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content">
        <div class="w3-container">
            <p>Some text. Some text. Some text.</p>
            <p>Some text. Some text. Some text.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo a documentação em: [dayClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline/dayClick/)

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view, resourceObj) {

    alert('Date: ' + date.format());
    alert('Resource ID: ' + resourceObj.id);

    }
});
```

no lugar de `alert` você pode colocar o seu modal:

```
$('#seuModal').dialog(); //por exemplo
```

Comment: Ainda não to conseguindo.

Comment: Quando você abre o `Developer Tools`, em `Console` aparece algum erro?

Comment: Não funciona o método

Comment: Qual o nome do método?

Comment: Consegui ^^. dei uma olhada no site da bootstrap